# Finding a geodesic between two points on the geometric realization of a connected graph.

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

I want to find an explicit geodesic between two points on the geometric realization of a connected graph.

It is intuitively clear that the geometric realization of a connected graph is a geodesic space, but I don't know how to find an explicit geodesic between two arbitrary elements on it.

Thanks!

Here is my proof:
The geometric realization of a connected graph is obtained by identifying each edge with a unit interval.
Assume Y is the geometric realization of the connected graph X=(V,E).
$\left ((u,v),t  \right )$ is the point on Y between the vertices u and v at the time $t\in [0,1]$ where {u,v} is in E. Let $((u,v),t),((a,b),s)\in Y$. Assume $d_{X}(u,b)=n$= minmal length of a path P connecting u and b in X. Say $P=u=u_{0},....,u_{n}=b$. Let I=[0,n], then $I= \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}I_{i}$ where $I_{i}$ is the unit interval $[i-1,i], i=1,...,n.$ Define:
$ \theta_{i} :[i-1,i]\rightarrow Y$ by
$\theta_{i}(t)=\frac{i-t}{i}u_{i-1}+\frac{t}{i}u_{i}$ and then define $\theta:[0,n]\rightarrow Y$ by $\theta (t)=\theta _{i}(t)$ if t is in 
[i-1,i]. Then $\theta:[0,n]\rightarrow Y$ is (continuous by the pasting lemma) a geodesic between u and b and hence $\theta |_{[t,s]}$ is a geodesic between $((u,v),t),((a,b),s)\in Y$.

Is there anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: Don’t you have to define the geometry with a Metric?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is the [depth first search algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: It is far from clear what an "explicit" means here: Imagine a random connected graph on $10^{10}$ vertices given in terms of its incidence matrix. Also, what does this question have to do with group theory? (Unless your graph is a Cayley graph.)

Comment: Yes, my graph is a Cayley graph.